# Getter и Setter для указателя

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки

Вопрос заключается в том, как правильно реализовать `Getter` для указателя, чтобы он был "безопасным". Под безопасностью я подразумеваю предотвращение несанкционированного удаления указателя. Давайте рассмотрим пример:

```cpp
class MediaSettings
{
public:

    // ...

    virtual bool isValid() noexcept = 0;

    // ...
};

class AudioSettings : public MediaSettings
{
public:

    // ...

    virtual bool isValid() noexcept override;

    // ...
};

class MediaRecorder
{
public:

    // ...

    void setSettings(MediaSettings* settings) noexcept;
    const MediaSettings* getSettings()  const noexcept;

    // ...

protected:

    QScopedPointer<MediaSettings> p_settings{ nullptr };
};

const MediaSettings* MediaRecorder::getSettings() const noexcept
{
    return p_settings ? p_settings.get() : nullptr;
}
```

И пример использования:

```cpp
MediaRecorder recorder;
MediaSettings* settings = new AudioSettings(...);
if (settings->isValid) {
    recorder.setSettings(settings);
}
```

Является ли эта реализация действительной, и если нет, смогли бы вы предоставить правильное решение. Я думал о возвращении ссылки, но в этом случае, при любом раскладе, настройки мультимедиа не должны указывать на `nullptr`.

Я также где-то слышал, что нежелательно возвращать ссылку или указатель на скрытую переменную.

Comment: Если возвращаемое значение опциональное, то возвращайте `::boost::optional<MediaSettings const &>` или делайте отдельный обязательный метод для предварительной проверки наличия или функцию обратного вызова c передачей ссылки.

Comment: imho вы все усложняете, накручиваете совершенно лишнюю инкапсуляцию

Comment: Что такое "несанкционированного удаления указателя"? Вероятно, вам просто нужен указатель с подсчётом ссылок, например, `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @avp, что вы подразумеваете под лишней инкапсуляцией ? Идея заключается в том, что существует общий интерфейс - `MediaSettings`, и класс `AudioSettings`, который наследует интерфейс. Это делается потому, что в будущем может появиться класс `VideoSettings`, содержащий совершенно другие настройки. Для этого я и создал интерфейс для разграничения настроек. `MediaRecorder` принимает интерфейс настроек, и в зависимости от того, какие настройки я ему дам (настройки видео или аудио), он создаст поток для записи аудио или видео.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, возможно я неправильно выразился. Я имею ввиду то, что если при получение указателя от метода `get`, я могу его удалить, то есть вероятность, что я это сделаю случайно (или кто-то другой).

Comment: @bbdd, я подразумеваю, что вам надо просто  использовать указатель (поле в структуре MediaRecorder) и ничего более (KISS принцип)

Comment: @avp, прошу прощения, возможно я Вас неправильно понял, но разве у меня не то, о чем Вы написали ? `MediaRecorder` имеет метод `setSettings`, который принимает указатель на интерфейс. Обворачиваю я его в `QScopedPointer` просто, что бы в будущем не думать об уничтожение `MediaSeconds`.

Comment: Проблема сырого указателя не в том, что зная его, можно удалить объект, на который он указывает, а в том, что нельзя быть уверенным в его валидности в долгосрочной перспективе. Никто "случайно" не удаляет, это можно сделать только намеренно. А вот чтобы как-то гарантировать живучесть как раз и придумали умные указатели с подсчётом ссылок.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, я с Вами согласен. Изначально,`QScopedPointer` был использован именно для запрета копирования (так как идея была в том, что `MediaSettings` в принцепе, не должны копироваться).

Comment: Ну так используйте `QSharedPointer`, например, и внутри, и при возврате.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, так и сделаю. Спасибо за комментарии.

Comment: @bbdd, конечно, неправильно. Я о том, что **никакие** get/set не нужны. Нужно просто аккуратно писать код

Comment: @avp, смогли ли бы Вы предоставить пример того, как с Вашей точки зрения, должен выглядеть данный пример.

Comment: @avp, почему у меня есть и `setter`, а для того, чтобы предотвратить присваивание `nullptr` напрямую. Если я подам `nullptr` в существующий `setSettings`, то он просто проигнорирует это присваивание, ибо это 0. Но, что будет, если я сделаю что то подобное: `recorder.settings = nullptr;` Думаю, это хороший аргумент в использование `setter-a` (именно в данной реализации).

Comment: @bbdd, ну, весь код должен быть согласованным. Когда логика задчи требует `recorder.settings = 0;` пишите, когда не требует -- не пишите. Собственно, проверять на правильность нужно внешние для программы данные, а не каждый шаг в коде.

Comment: @avp, на счет того, что проверять на правильность нужно внешние для программы данные, я с Вами согласен (аргументация очень понравилась, правда). Но все же, в данной реализации, я имею метод `isValid`, так как пользователь устанавливает значения аудио или видео настроек. Например, если пользователь введет несуществующий кодек аудио, метод `isValid` вернет `false`, ибо такого кодека не существует. Вот для чего, я проверяю валидность настроек. Что скажете, насчет данного нюанса ?

Comment: @avp, Может быть и в правду убрать проверку и сделать это в том модуле, где это будет более уместно (например, перед самим созданием медиа стрима, который и запросит данные настройки) ?

Comment: @bbdd, скажу, что `if (settings->isValid) recorder.p_settings = settings;` ничем не хуже вашего `if (settings->isValid) {  recorder.setSettings(settings); }` / А проверку надо делать там, где она наиболее логична (желательно как можно ближе к точке, где появились эти данные)

Comment: @avp, полностью согласен с Вами. Благодарю за уместную и полезную критику.

Answer (score 0):

Предложу  вариант попроще:

```
class MediaRecorder
{
public:
    // ...
    void setSettings(const MediaSettings& settings) noexcept
    {
        //проверить, валидные ли параметры аудио настроек
        //Учитывая, что вызов `isValid` должен быть разрешен и для константных объектов,
        // и метод нужно объявить с квалификатором const
        valid = settings.isValid();
    }  
    void disable() noexcept { if (valid) valid = false; }
    operator bool() { return valid; }
    // ...
protected:
    bool valid{};        
};
```

Пример использования:

```
MediaRecorder recorder;
recorder.setSettings(AudioSettings());
// ...    
if (recorder) {        
   qDebug()  << "Audio settings is not valid";
   // ...         
}
```

Но как лучше _ зависит от реализации и намерений...